# Creating flowchart for QGIS using GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal

Currently I have thousands of animal trails and I want to analyse the network to see which waterholes trails lead to or if they are fragmented by roads. I tried exporting the CSV file to gephi another software that analyses networks but it does not create a flow chart. So I'm wondering if I could do a flowchart on QGIS using GDAL.

Below is a partial of my project:

[image]

And I am aiming to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the trail network and an example of what you want to obtain? Even an example from a different context would help.

Answer (score 3):

I will expand on this if needed, but you can create a sort of heatmap with `gdal_rasterize`, which can be accessed through the Toolbox (gear icon).

Make sure to use the `-burn 1 -add` options,si that the command reads like this:

`gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -add -tr 50 50 -l lines yourlines.shp hotnodes.tif`

Basically a raster is created, and in each pixel is assigned a value equal to the number of times a line crosses it.

https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html